# Hyperledger Fabric Support for Production

Tags: hyperledger

I would like to bring Hyperledger Fabric in production. Who will support the platform in case of software issues? Is there any credited Company (e.g. like Red-Hat or Suse for Linux?)

Within my Company we are running some PoC/MVP using Hyperledger Fabric, with very encouraging results. We are thinking to move in production environement but we don't feel comfortable with the platform support: if we have an issue in the code, we have to fix by oursleves... or?

I wonder if any of you guys have experience with Hyperledger Fabric in production and how do you support the platform. Do you rely to any Hyperledger Fabric expertise/company/ etc?

We need a "Red-Hat" for Hyperledger Fabric, same way RHEL or SUSE made for Linux...

I would appreciate your view and feedback guys.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found this dev post article really helpful in your type of situation do check it out!

[Hyperledger Fabric: Transitioning from Development to Production](https://dev.to/presto412/hyperledger-fabric-transitioning-from-development-to-production-4dch)

Answer (score 0):

As much as i know, Hyperledger fabric is not backed by any Company.
If you want some support for Hyperledger Fabric you can find some help on Rocket chat of Hyperledger.
If you really need an active support for production you can find some paid engagement with company like Amazon, Microsoft or IBM as they provide Hyperledger fabric on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

it's backed by IBM for production.